# How to pass mouse clicks through TLF text?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, tlf

The `.mouseEnabled` doesn't work like it does on usual MovieClips. What's up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `selectable`, `mouseEnabled`, `mouseChildren`, and for giggles `mouseWheelEnabled` all to false

Comment: Thanks a lot! this problem has been plaguing me all day! I've found that you need both mouseEnabled, and mouseChildren. Enabled only seems to disable mouse interaction with the text while children affects the whole hitbox around the text, but not the text itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 text_field.mouseEnabled = false;
 text_field.mouseChildren = false;
```

mouseChildren means it's children don't register mouse events, they just dispatch from the parent. To completely disable it, BOTH need to be false.

Since the textfield is a child of the movie clip, the mouseChildren property is what is going to affect it, and you could just set that to false and it would still work.